# Me and my ancestors - single word

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns

I'd like to find a single noun that relates to me and which corresponds to the list of people including `me and each of my ancestors`.

I've already rejected the following words:

- `genealogy` : means a work, not a list of people.
- `ancestry` : seems to exclude `me`.

Comment: Do you just mean your forebears or all of the collateral relatives as well?

Comment: Only my parents, their parents, etc. Not any siblings, unless they're part of the parents (ugh).

Comment: There isn't a word for this.

Comment: It's unfortunately possible, and that's an acceptable answer until there is such a word ;)

Comment: In genealogy, there is the word "clade" that means an individual life entity and all its descendants, pretty much the opposite of what is being asked for here. I've searched for and not found a word meaning an individual and all its ancestors. I'd suggest that if "clade" is jargon that most people don't know about, then any word with the requested meaning is going to be more obscure still. I'd therefore advise to use the phrase "me and my ancestors" which is concise, unambiguous and widely understood.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Heinlein's "All You Zombies" comes to mind...

Comment: By the way, you can't use a negative word like `unfortunately` with a positive word like `possible`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> [line of descent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/line+of+descent).
>
> Noun - the kinship relation between an individual and the individual's
>   progenitors.
>     ≡filiation, lineage, descent

(TFD)

Answer (score 44):

> **[lineage](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/lineage)**:
>
> The word lineage is used to describe everyone who descends from a
>   particular ancestor.

- (***n***) the ***kinship*** relation between an individual and the individual's
  progenitors. (vocabulary.com)

> Probably you are looking for
>   **bilateral descent** : 
>   line of descent traced through both the maternal and paternal sides of the family
>   .

- Descent in a line from a common progenitor, descending line of offspring or ascending line of parentage. ([wiki](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lineage))

Comment: I'm not sure it can be used the way the OP intends. Lineage is synonymous with ancestry in form if not definition. Also th OP specified "each of his ancestors; lineage singles out one only: ["direct descent from an ancestor, esp a line of descendants from one ancestor"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lineage).

Comment: This definition of lineage seems to be one grand-father, his children and his grand-children (including me), not the other way around.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire agree, until there is such a word : ) -

Comment: I just thought about it, but could I use `my lineages` (plural form)?

Answer (score 19):

How about **Bloodline** ?

All the members of a family group over generations, esp regarding characteristics common to that group; pedigree

**EDIT:**
It will be unlikely to have such a single word in any language as it would be rather wasteful to have a word that cannot be used to talk about forebears other than the speakers or writers own and this is a rather rare need.  Almost all the other words offered will still have to be qualified with **my** or **of mine** to make sense and so fail the single word requirement in a way.

If OP has no children he can use two words to accurately fulfil the requirements with **My bloodline** which will include OP, however children would usually be included in the bloodline if they exist.

Comment: Is it me or does this carry the weight of `my children` too?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire You are correct I think, not seen much mention about OPs children so perhaps subconsciously thinking he might not have any yet and he would be the culmination of his bloodline, optimistic thinking I suppose. I still like the word as it hints at the chain of ancestors that OP was asking about. "Forebears and me" is probably the closest that one can get to exclude all others.

Answer (score 9):

***[Family tree](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/family-tree)***, though two words, is a useful expression to refer to yourself and your predecessors:

> - A diagram showing the relationships between people in several generations of a family; ***a genealogical tree***.

(ODO)

[image]

Comment: This bears too much the sense of group of people, not list of people (this is acceptable though). Also, can easily be confused to include siblings at any level (but this is not acceptable).

Comment: You are  asking for an expression that refers to "me and each of my ancestors*". I think a family tree is close to that definition. –

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire - if you check the diagram, you can see that the tree refers to you, your parents, their parents, etc, which seems what you are looking for. I think it is called *direct line of descent*.

Comment: You're right, the diagram refers to me. The definition refers to siblings as well and that's what I disagree with. I specifically excluded siblings.

Comment: "A family tree with only the direct line of descent"

Comment: I could accept 2-3 words. but this starts to be a lot.

Comment: That is the concept you are after, your question  should be: one word for 'family tree of direct line of descent'.

Comment: This is not what was asked: a family tree is a graphic *representation* of a set of people and their relationships, not the set of related people itself. This is like using the term *trial transcript* to mean a trial, or using the term *score* to refer to what you hear at a concert.

Answer (score 4):

Several good suggestions have been made here already.

One more possibility:

> [Pedigree](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pedigree): The recorded ancestry [or lineage] of a person or family. (Oxford)

Comment: +1, however,IMO- pedigree is evocative of the ancestry of a purebred animal.

Comment: @Mysti Indeed, pedigree is most often used with regards to purebred animals. I too think of animals first when I hear *pedigree* but since the OP hasn't found what he's looking for yet, I decided it was worth a shot.  But I should probably have mentioned the purebred thing in my post.

Comment: `Pedigree` seems to lose the inclusion of `me`, showing only ancestors. "This person is [...] because of his pedigree". Am I wrong?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I would probably say yes, technically the definition does seem to lose the inclusion of me. But there is a certain ambiguity regarding *pedigree* that many people understand it to be the person (me) or animal as a result of all its ancestors.  So in that way it does include *me* .  If you're looking for a single word answer, this is probably the closest I can get to that.

Comment: The word is same as ancestry but a recorded one. It also means the genealogical chart so the chart can include you and your ancestors; but it starts from the progenitor.

Answer (score 3):

In geneology studies, there is a report often created called an *[ahnentafel report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahnentafel)*

> a genealogical numbering system for listing a person's direct ancestors in a fixed sequence of ascent. The subject (proband or progenitor) of the ahnentafel is listed as No. 1, the subject's father as No. 2 and the mother as No. 3, the paternal grandparents as No. 4 and No. 5 and the maternal grandparents as No. 6 and No. 7, and so on, back through the generations.

*Wikipedia*

While the term is originally German, it is routinely used in English language genealogy activities.

This term describes the report rather than the relationship, but it may suit, depending on the context of your usage.

Answer (score 1):

> **progenitor** (*pro·gen·i·tor/prōˈjenədər*)
>   noun  -
>   a person or thing from which a person, animal, or plant is descended or originates; an ancestor or parent.

Progenitor is more generic than say, `bloodline` and overall depending on context, `progenitors` can be implisivitly inclusive to the individual making the statement.

Comment: "Progenitor" fails to include the person.

Answer (score 1):

You and your ancestors are kin.

**kin**, noun -[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kin)

> 1. a person's relatives collectively; kinfolk.
> 2. family relationship or kinship.
> 3. a group of persons descended from a common ancestor or constituting a people, clan, tribe, or family.
> 4. a relative or kinsman.

**kindred** [kin-drid] noun -[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kindred)

> 1. a person's relatives collectively; kinfolk; kin.
> 2. a group of persons related to another; family, tribe, or clan.
> 3. relationship by birth or descent, or sometimes by marriage; kinship.

Admittedly, some of one's kin may be 'related' through marriage. We can differentiate from this by using *blood kin*.

**blood kin**, noun -[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blood%20kin)

> *relatives* :  those that are kin by reason of common ancestry; *also* :  a group united by blood bond

Or just cut to the chase and use *kinship*.

**kinship** /ˈkinˌSHip/ noun -[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=kinship&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

> blood relationship.