# Is there a word that describes the group of words used to describe familial relations?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not at all sure if such a word exists but I feel like it has to. I think my title was enough but, to make it more clear when I say familial relationship words I mean words like dad, uncle, niece, cousin, etc. English doesn't have a lot but other languages have very complex relational nouns depending which side of the family they're from, gender, and levels of relation. I feel like it's probably an important enough linguistic concept to warrent a name.

Comment: *kinship terms* (https://www.thoughtco.com/what-are-kinship-terms-1691092) If anyone answers this question, they'll probably be downvoted for it, just so you know.

Comment: @HippoSawrUs, you should probably make that an answer, as answers in comments are often deleted on ELU.

Comment: @Peter - Tell it to the GR Police. It's probably mentioned on here elsewhere anyhow.

Comment: Appreciate it, HippoSawrUs. The answer is essentially given at [me and my ancestors ... single word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257325/me-and-my-ancestors-single-word/257443#257443) (though the question is hyponymic).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That question and its answers seems more specific than this.

Comment: When you're looking for a technical term in a field of study, I generally recommend asking on the site for that field. In this case, [linguistics.se].

Comment: @Barmar 'the question is hyponymic' = 'that question  seems more specific than this' and 'kinship' is _not_ a more specific answer.

Comment: Meanwhile IRL, the peak of *kinship* fame coincides with the LotR trilogy years… The movies, of course.